# paralleling nested loops

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, nested-loops

I'm trying parallelize some nested loops using pool, moreover function have to return an array, but external array stays empty.

```
def calcul_T(m):
    temp=[]
    for n in range(0,N):
        x = sym.Symbol('x')
        y=sym.sin(x)

        #.....some stuff.....

        temp.append(y)
    
    return temp

rt=[]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    rt.append(pool.map(calcul_T, range(0,M)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I expect getting at least array of arrays in order to make it 2-D array and then use it further, after `if __name__` block

What do I wrong?

Comment: I guess it should be `rt = list(pool.map(calcul_T, range(0,M)))`

Comment: rt is still empty(

Comment: `for n in range(0, m)` ?

Comment: no, m used further in function and for goes in (0, N), where N is global

Answer (score 1):

Use context manager:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def calcul_T(m):
    temp=[]
    for n in range(0,N):
        x = sym.Symbol('x')
        y=sym.sin(x)

        #.....some stuff.....

        temp.append(y)
    
    return temp

rt=[]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(N_PROCESSES) as p:
        rt = p.map(calcul_T, range(0,M))
```

**EDIT**

According to comment, accesing rt like normal 2D array works just fine (run in console, i changed calcul_T function for running this)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
N = 10
M = 10
def calcul_T(m):
    temp=[]
    for n in range(0,N):
        temp.append(n * m)
    return temp

rt = []

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    with Pool(5) as p:
        rt = p.map(calcul_T, range(0,M))
    
    print(rt[8][8])
```

Comment: can you explain please how I should get values from "rt" after ".map"
rt[m][n], rt[m,n] don't really work

Comment: for example 

for m in range(0,M):
    for n in range(0,N):

        T=T+rt[m][n]

Comment: I am running my code in console from .py file, and later in code I can use rt[][] normally like a 2-D array. I think that issue may not be in pool itself, but how you are using rt later

Comment: actually there is code without multitasking and it works excellent, all I do with rt is getting values from it like
`for m in range(0,M):
    for n in range(0,N):

        T=T+rt[m][n]`